# When installing a new extension, what is the Installation priority between installscript.php and sql file within the manifest.xml?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hello I am developing a component and I need to know which is executed first, the installscript.php that is declared as an installation script within the manifest.xml or the install_data.sql ?

Comment: firstly run manifest then in manifest found <installfile> tag then installscripts runs

Comment: after some extended research, I found this document , http://docs.joomla.org/Managing_Component_Updates_with_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_3 . So according to that document, Install method is executed after the Joomla install database scripts have completed. Returning 'false' will abort the install and undo any changes already made. It is cleaner to abort the install during preflight, if possible. Since fewer install actions have occurred at preflight, there is less risk that that their reversal may be done incorrectly.
But the preflight method is executed first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So according to that document, Install method is executed after the
>   Joomla install database scripts have completed. - You